# Overlapping text in the res class.

Tags: sectioning, margins, resume, cv

I'm writing a resume using `\documentclass[50 pt, margin]{res}` and I got the `res.cls` from http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/. I'm new to LaTeX (this is my second document) and when I typeset the last letter of the section header overlaps the first letter of the content. I'm not sure how to fix it without adding odd line break or changing words.

This is the line:

```
\section{ORGANIZATIONS}
    Association Name \hfill \textbf{Fall 2011 - Current} \\
```

Comment: [`res`](http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/res.cls) does not support a `50pt` document class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\section` under [`res`](http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/res.cls) is redefined in a strange way. From the source, it's usage is given as

```
%   \section{text}
%       This prints 'text' in the left hand margin.
%       Its exact placement depends on what the style 
%       options has been set to. (overlapped or margin)
%       You should use \\ to start a new line.  If the
%       style option is margin, the \\ is converted
%       to a space.
%       To use this in any of the list environments, put
%       the \section after the \item[] but before the 
%       text.
%       Eg.
%       \begin{itemize}
%       \item\section{text}
%       text
%       \end{itemize}
```

Under the `margin` class option, the default width of the sections are `1.3in`, while the `overlap` class option sets it to `0.5in`. You can adjust these settings manually via `\newsectionwidth{<width>}`. In your case, perhaps using `\newsectionwidth{1.5in}` would be sufficient. I'm not sure how this might affect the other document contents...

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin]{res}% http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/res.cls
\newsectionwidth{1.5in}
\begin{document}
\section{ORGANIZATIONS}
    Association Name \hfill \textbf{Fall 2011 - Current}
\end{document}
```

As a point of suggestion: Consider a more recent class for setting your résumé. Something like [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv), for example.